# UserNames search by wildcard Nakama Api

Tags: nakama

HiIs there a way to search and get users by usernames with wildcard?

Usecase: I want the search username not case sensitive, if i search either name is capital letter or small if it is got username then still show.

I tried adding * or % in prefix and/or suffix but it’s not working in function

In Nakama console it says use % for wildcard search, but it’s not working
I am using Postgres database and golang server routine

```
function rpcCheckUser(
    ctx: nkruntime.Context,
    logger: nkruntime.Logger,
    nk: nkruntime.Nakama,
    payload: string
  ): any {   
    
    logger.info('Check Username Availability rpc called.');

    try {
      const payloadParse = JSON.parse(payload);
      const usernameToCheck = payloadParse.username;
  
      const users = nk.usersGetUsername([usernameToCheck]);
      
      if (users && users.length > 0) {
        return 'true';
      } else {
        return 'false';
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      return JSON.stringify({ error: "Invalid payload format" });
    }
  }
```